# Adding class to image from database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image, tags, image-resizing

Iv created a panel to show an image in view that a user uploads however I would like the photo to fit the panel. Im new at this and I want to know where to place my class or sizing when it relates when bringing in the image from the data base, below is the string of code without class/sizing of photo. where to I place the class in the string. many thanks

```
<%= image_tag @photos[0].image.url(), class: "img-responsive" if @photos.length > 0 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap went to my CSS and simply added img class and it worked for another unrelated problem:

```
img {width: 100%;}
```